/proc/iomem shows multiple memory maps
Greetings! We have a single Intel NIC card attached that lspci lists as below and NIC driver is 'ixgbe'.  The /proc/iomem shows multiple  memory mapped for ther driver ixgbe, 81:00.0, and 81:00.1. I believe the memory is assigned only for ports(81:00.0 and 81:00.1). Could you please make me understanding why different allocations with duplicates. TIA.
1.) lspci shows one NIC with two ports.
81:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
81:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)```


2.) /proc/iomem shows multiple entries for that NIC.
3355443200 to 3372220415 bytes (3200 to 3215 Mb) - ixgbe  <-- 15 Mb
3372220416 to 3388997631 bytes (3216 to 3231 Mb) - ixgbe  <-- 15 Mb
3388997632 to 3389014015 bytes (3232 to 3232 Mb) - ixgbe  <-- 0 Mb
3389014016 to 3389030399 bytes (3232 to 3232 Mb) - ixgbe  <-- 0 Mb


355443200 to 3390046207 bytes (3200 to 3232 Mb) - PCI Bus 0000:81   <-- 32 Mb
3355443200 to 3372220415 bytes (3200 to 3215 Mb) - 0000:81:00.1     <-- 15 Mb
3372220416 to 3388997631 bytes (3216 to 3231 Mb) - 0000:81:00.0     <-- 15 Mb
3388997632 to 3389014015 bytes (3232 to 3232 Mb) - 0000:81:00.1     <-- 0 Mb
3389014016 to 3389030399 bytes (3232 to 3232 Mb) - 0000:81:00.0     <-- 0 Mb


4123168604160 to 4123172798463 bytes (3932160 to 3932163 Mb) - PCI Bus 0000:81  <-- 3 Mb
4123168604160 to 4123169652735 bytes (3932160 to 3932160 Mb) - 0000:81:00.0     <-- 0 Mb
4123169652736 to 4123170701311 bytes (3932161 to 3932161 Mb) - 0000:81:00.0     <-- 0 Mb
4123170701312 to 4123171749887 bytes (3932162 to 3932162 Mb) - 0000:81:00.1     <-- 0 Mb
4123171749888 to 4123172798463 bytes (3932163 to 3932163 Mb) - 0000:81:00.1     <-- 0 Mb

